# Converting a string into a link in an email

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, hyperlink, web-config

I am trying to send an email to a supervisor when a work order is created

```
    if(TextBox9.Text=="Quality"&&affectedrows==true)
    {
    boolisLocal=HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal;
    if(isLocal==true)
    {
    System.Net.Mail.MailMessagenn=newSystem.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
    nn.From=newSystem.Net.Mail.MailAddress("no_reply_workorder@mover.com");//whosend
    nn.To.Add(newSystem.Net.Mail.MailAddress("someone.something@mover.com"));

    nn.Subject="WorkOrdersTypeQuality";
    HttpFileCollectionuploadFiles=Request.Files;
    for(inti=0;i<uploadFiles.Count;i++)
    {
    HttpPostedFileuserpostedfils=uploadFiles[i];
    try
    {
    if(userpostedfils.ContentLength>0)
    {
    nn.Attachments.Add(newAttachment(userpostedfils.InputStream,Path.GetFileName(userpostedfils.FileName)));
    }
    }

    catch
    {
    Labelstatusmessage=(Label)DetailsView1.FindControl("lblmessage");
    statusmessage.Text="UploadFailedPleaseContactDeveloper";
    }
    }
    nn.Body="DONOTREPLYTOTHISEMAIL"+"<br><br/>"+"WorkOrderNumber"+":&nbsp;"+
"<ahref=\"http://localhost:49695/QualityReport.aspx?WorkOrderNum="+TextBox13.Text+"\">"+TextBox13.Text+"</a>"+"<-ClickontheWorkOrderNumberForReport"+"<br><br/>"+"WorkOrderNumber"+
":&nbsp;"+"<ahref=\"http://localhost:49695/Quality.aspx?WorkOrderNum="+TextBox13.Text+"\">"+TextBox13.Text+"</a>"+"<-ClickontheWorkOrderNumberToEnterData"+"<br><br/>"+"Requestor"+
":&nbsp;"+TextBoxRequestor.Text+"<br><br/>"+"Date"+":&nbsp;"+
TextBoxDate.Text+"<br><br/>"+"Department"+":&nbsp;"+
TextBox14.Text+"<br><br/>"+"CompletionDate"+":&nbsp;"+
TextBoxCompletionDate.Text+"<br><br/>"+"MachineDescription"+
":&nbsp;"+TextBoxMachineDescription.Text+"<br><br/>"+
"MachineLocation"+":&nbsp;"+TextBoxMachineLocation.Text+
"<br><br/>"+"WorkRequired"+":&nbsp;"+TextBoxWorkRequired.Text+
"<br><br/>"+"Status"+":&nbsp;"+TextBoxStatus.Text;
    nn.IsBodyHtml=true;
    System.Net.Mail.SmtpClientclient=newSystem.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
    client.Host=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpServer"];
    captureuseremail();
    }
    }
```

in the body of the mail I am sending an link to the workorder that just got created, "http://server01/WorkOrder/QualityReport.aspx?WorkOrderNum="TextBox13.Text+"\">" I am working on four different plants so I need to deploy each project to 4 servers and change the link above to server02, server03, and server04 and there are 3 types of workorders so I was thinking of storing each link into a key in web.config:

```
 <add key ="safetylink" value="http://server01/WorkOrderTool/SafetyReport.aspx?WorkOrderNum="/>
```

Get the value from web.config and store as string and use it in the email  I am not sure how to do that:

```
 string safetylink = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["safetylink"];
 mm.Body = "DO NOT REPLY TO THIS EMAIL" + "<br><br/>" + "WorkOrderNumber" + ": &nbsp;" + "<a href=\"safetylink" + TextBox13.Text + "\">"
```

but that does not work, by doing the above I hope to simple deploy one web application to 4 servers and go into each ones web.config and change the name of the server instead of find and replace.

Thank You in advance coders

Comment: Does what you tried throw a `DoesNotWorkException` ?

Comment: use `"<a href=\"" + safetylink"` instead of `"<a href=\"safetylink"`.

Comment: it doesn't throw any error it just sends an email such as  workorder: 21 21 will be a hyperlink and when they click 21 it takes them to http:\\safetylink\\

Comment: you should [Use the debugger](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-A-Beginn) to inspect what your `Body` looks at before you send it

Comment: @SamIam yea your answer fixed my issue I had to add the link after the + thanks bud appreciate it

Comment: @SamIam what if you have something like this                             HtmlMeta meta = new HtmlMeta();
                    meta.HttpEquiv = "Refresh";
                    meta.Content = "3;url=http://server01/WorkOrderTool/CreateWorkOrder.aspx"; 
                    this.Page.Controls.Add(meta);                                                                                                                    how do you replace the url= then have the string I tried + and string it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

thanks to SamIam anytime you want to sent a string as a hyperlink in the body of an email:

```
use "<a href=\"" + yourstringname"
```